# Problems creating interactions terms

Tags: r, regression, interaction, model.matrix

I have a data.frame with 7000 rows and 36 columns. Some of the column are categorial variables.
Now I want create a x matrix for a regression by using model.matrix.
In that matrix should be interactions terms like (V1*V2*V3).
I tried to do that like this :

```
formelhas <- formula(k ~ .^3)
 test <-  model.matrix(formelhas,testahah)
```

Testaha is the data frame.

In the result test has only interactions terms like (V1*V2) no third order interactions (V1*V2*V3) terms. Why?

Answer (score 0):

It will be difficult to answer this without further information from you about the data structures.

The code you've given *should* work, which suggests you've possibly made some kind of simple typographical error. To confirm that, let's do a quick reproducible example and see that three-way interactions are indeed generated from similar code from a built-in dataset:

No interactions:

```
> str(colnames(model.matrix(mpg ~ ., mtcars)))
 chr [1:11] "(Intercept)" "cyl" "disp" "hp" "drat" "wt" "qsec" "vs" "am" "gear" "carb"
```

Two-way interactions:

```
> str(colnames(model.matrix(mpg ~ .^2, mtcars)))
 chr [1:56] "(Intercept)" "cyl" "disp" "hp" "drat" "wt" "qsec" "vs" "am" "gear" "carb" "cyl:disp" ...
```

Three-way interactions:

```
> str(colnames(model.matrix(mpg ~ .^3, mtcars)))
 chr [1:176] "(Intercept)" "cyl" "disp" "hp" "drat" "wt" "qsec" "vs" "am" "gear" "carb" "cyl:disp" ...
```

Are they actually there?

```
> tail(colnames(model.matrix(mpg ~ .^3, mtcars)))
[1] "qsec:am:carb"   "qsec:gear:carb" "vs:am:gear"     "vs:am:carb"     "vs:gear:carb"   "am:gear:carb"
```

Yes, yes they are. So, your code *should* work. Perhaps you're just misinterpreting something?